# how to sort a list of tuples by two items toghether python

Tags: sorting

`mylist = [('Action',1) , ('Horror',2) , ('Adventure',0) , ('History',2) , ('Romance',1) ,('Comedy',1)]`

i have a list of tuples like that:

```
Action: 1
Horror: 2
Adventure: 0
History: 2
Romance: 1
Comedy: 1
```

i want to sort this by two elements (name(Alphabetically) & value)

my result should be :

```
History: 2
Horror: 2
Action: 1
Comedy: 1
Romance: 1
Adventure: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(0,1), reverse=True)
```

You can read more about this approach in the "Operator Module Functions" section of this doc:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Comment: you need `from operator import itemgetter` and yet the result is not what OP wants

Comment: True, I've made some changes but the answer is still not what the OP wants. Close but not perfect

Comment: but this code that you suggested, doeasn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [('Action',1) , ('Horror',2) , ('Adventure',0) , ('History',2) , ('Romance',1) ,('Comedy',1)]

category = defaultdict(list)

for item in mylist:
    category[item[1]].append(item[0])

sorted(category.items())
keylist = category.keys()
for key in sorted(keylist, reverse = True):
    valuelist = category[key]
    valuelist.sort()
    category[key] = valuelist
    for v in valuelist:
        print(str(v),str(key))
```

Output is below:

```
History 2
Horror 2
Action 1
Comedy 1
Romance 1
Adventure 0
```